# Guidance on Java issue on Mac

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have come across a major wall and hopefully someone can help me out.

**Preface:**
We have a desktop application (JavaFX based). It speaks to Canon camera using Canon's SDK. Hence one can download the latest Image taken, get notifications about camera events and so on. And it works all well on Windows.

Now the SDK is 32-bit based and hence the JVM we use has to be 32-bit based (64-bit JVM is incompatible, fullstop).

**Coming to Mac**

There is no Java-7 for 32-bit Mac. Hence we have got to us Java-6 which is no Issue (WIth `-d32` VM argument). But it turns out that there is no Java-FX for Java6 on Mac. How can I bundle my application with Java6 and Java-FX? Any nightly build wil help? Or any other manual tweaks? Else it will demand a lot of restructuring of the code.

Comment: Use a 32-bit java app (daemon?) for the camera, and a 64-bit app for the rest. Then communicate between the apps, for instance via RMI.

Comment: If Canon supports Java on Mac, they will need to make a 64-bit version.  Have you asked?

Comment: Does this need to work on _all Macs_ or just _a Mac_? I had the same issue with Chrome and you can [downgrade java](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559).

Comment: @JoopEggen We plan to port Java along to the client so that he doesn't download if there is no Java on his machine. For the case you mentioned, I will have to port Java7 and Java6 also. Any smart way of doing it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They do have a 64 bit mode, bit it is still in beta. Plus a lot of functions do not work in it.

Comment: @bmorris591 its for common people working on mac. So yes all Macs

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen they dont support java on Mac. I have written a wrapper using JNA to their `framework`.

Comment: Not so smart, me. Though the effort porting two Java generations should not be much more than one. Considering that at some point in future you will want to go to at least Java 7 (if not 8).

Comment: You may end up having a Java 6 backend talking to a Java 7 frontend. Considered making a separate 32-bit application just for talking to the SDK under OS X and then communicate with that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes. THe only issue is I will have to port 2 runtimes along :(